# How can I use multiple res.renders in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm making a web application using Express.js in Node.js that tells the weather of the city the users input + a random Kanye west quote. For that purpose, I am using the data of **two APIs** so that I can fetch the data and display it in the **final.ejs** file, but how can I use two **res.renders** in my **app.js**.

**app.js**

```
    //jshint esversion: 6

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const https = require("https");

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 


app.listen(3000, function(req,res){
    console.log("Server started running on port 3000");
});

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res)
{
    let cityName = req.body.cityName;
    let weatherUrl = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + cityName + "&units=metric&appid=3c6398acf0105933ccb43e63d0fd8b18";
    https.get(weatherUrl, function(response)
    {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        response.on("data", function(data)
        {
            let weatherData = JSON.parse(data);
            let temp = weatherData.main.temp;
            let desc = weatherData.weather[0].description;

            res.render("final", {cityNameFinal: cityName, cityTemperature: temp, cityDescription: desc});
        });
    });

    let kanyeUrl = "https://api.kanye.rest/";
    https.get(kanyeUrl, function(response)
    {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        response.on("data", function(data)
        {
            let quoteDate = JSON.parse(data);
            let quote = quoteDate.quote;

            res.render("final", {kanyeQuote: quote});
        });
    });
});

//For the "Search for another city" button
app.post("/home", function(req, res){
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Jyotirmay Patel" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Weather App</title>

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredericka+the+Great&family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Bootstrap Styles CDN -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body id="main">
    <h1 class="heading-1">Weather App</h1>
    <h1 class="heading-2">+ Random Kanye West Quotes</h1>
    <hr>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 main-container">
                <form action="/" method="POST">
                    <label class="city-label" for="">Please enter the City Name: </label>
                    <br>
                    <input class="cityName-input" type="text" name="cityName" id="" placeholder="Enter a City">
                    <br>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap Scripts CDN -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
</body>

</html>
```

**final.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Jyotirmay Patel" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Weather App</title>

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredericka+the+Great&family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="list-styles.css">

    <!-- Bootstrap Styles CDN -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body id="main">
    <h1 class="heading-first">Weather App</h1>
    <h1 class="heading-second">+ Random Kanye West Quotes</h1>
    <hr>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 main-container">
                <h1 class="heading-first"> <%= cityNameFinal %> </h1>
                <hr>
                <h2 class="heading-third">Temperature: <%= cityTemperature %> </h2>
                <h2 class="heading-third">Weather Description: <%= cityDescription %> </h2>
                <form action="/home" method="POST">
                    <button class="our-button" type="submit">Search for another City</button>
                </form>
                <hr>
                <h2 class="heading-fourth"> <%= kanyeQuote %> </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap Scripts CDN -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why not save the respons in a variable and return both together?

Comment: Can you please show me the code on how to achieve this, it's still not working

Comment: sure, maybe something like this https://codeshare.io/ax0Z4j

Comment: In this solution, how we'll assign the wRet data to different JavaScript variables used in the final.ejs file.

Comment: just add `weather.`  infront  of your weather variables